# Prestashop 1.5.1 - How can I import a product's shipping characteristics?

Tags: csv, import, prestashop

I am currently responsible of importing a large number of products to a client's database.
I've been using a CSV file to do this, but so far I haven't been able to correctly determine the shipping characteristics (eg: width, height, depth) of the product itself (Catalog > Products > Edit (Product XPTO > Shipping).

Inside the CSV file, I was trying to use:

```
(...);"Height:9 cm:1, Width:13,7 cm:2";(....)
```

and then, I would map this value to the Features (Name:Value:Position) column.
As a result, the product's height and width do appear on the product's datasheet, but so far I haven't managed to copy these values to the shipping tab.

How can this be done?
[Here's a sample CSV dummy file](http://pastebin.com/9UPCgWiM)

One more thing: what does the "Position" inside the Feature's Name:Value:Position list does? I was using soemthing like *Feature Name:Feature Value:increment* but as far as I can see, this isn't how it's supposed to be done.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** If possible, I would also like to know exactly what does the field "Value (Value:Position)*" refer to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product shipping characteristics are stored in the following fields of the `ps_product` table in the Prestashop database:

- width decimal(20,6)
- height decimal(20,6)
- depth decimal(20,6)

Unfortunately, the CSV import script (`controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php`) does not write those fields (have a look at the source code for further details) so, if you want to copy the Width, Height and Depth feature values into the corresponding fields of the "Shipping" tab, you have to run the following MySQL queries (**please do a backup of your database before proceeding**):

```
update ps_product p, 
       ps_feature_lang fl, 
       ps_feature_product fp, 
       ps_feature_value_lang fvl 
   set p.width=fvl.value 
 where p.id_product=fp.id_product 
   and fl.id_feature=fp.id_feature 
   and fl.name='Width' 
   and fvl.id_feature_value=fp.id_feature_value;

update ps_product p, 
       ps_feature_lang fl, 
       ps_feature_product fp, 
       ps_feature_value_lang fvl 
   set p.height=fvl.value 
 where p.id_product=fp.id_product 
   and fl.id_feature=fp.id_feature 
   and fl.name='Height' 
   and fvl.id_feature_value=fp.id_feature_value;

update ps_product p, 
       ps_feature_lang fl, 
       ps_feature_product fp, 
       ps_feature_value_lang fvl 
   set p.depth=fvl.value 
 where p.id_product=fp.id_product 
   and fl.id_feature=fp.id_feature 
   and fl.name='Depth' 
   and fvl.id_feature_value=fp.id_feature_value;
```

One notice: since the `ps_feature_value_lang.value` field is a `varchar(255)` whilst the `ps_product.width/height/depth` fields are `decimal(20,6), the queries update only the value, but not the measure unit.
This means that you have to set in your "Localization" settings the same "Dimension Unit" that you're using in your CSV file (for example, in your dummy file you are using "cm").
Finally, about the "Position" meaning: it's simply an ordinal used for displaying the various features in a certain order in the "Features" tab.
Even if I've not tried, it should be possible to add new product features from the CSV file, 
 so with the "Position" field you can also specify in which position these new features must be added.